# ASP.NET Event for User Control

Tags: asp.net

In aspx page, I am using a user control which contains a button. I need to hide the button(which is in user control) when a checkbox(in aspx) is clikced. I have a postback for checkbox. I want to hide the button when the checkbox is checked. In which event I should do the hiding and unhiding?

I cannot add extra property in user control. Is it possible to access the button using FindControl and disable it? Which event can be used for it?

Please help

Thanks

Lijo

Answer (score 0):

You would do the hiding in the checkbox clicked event.....

Is your question how to get you aspx page to talk to you ascx?

Expose a public method in your ascx and call it from your aspx onSelectChanged for your Checkbox

Answer (score 0):

```
    protected void myCheckBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ucMyControl.ButtonVisible = ((CheckBox)sender).Checked;
    }
```

and in your user control define:

```
    public bool ButtonVisible
    {
        set { myButton.Visible = value; }
    }
```

Comment: It shouldn't be the issue if it has Visible property

Comment: I cannot add extra property in user control. Is it possible to access the button using FindControl and disable it? Which event can be used for it?

Comment: well, it's possible if you have at least a reference to user control and know the button's ID. You need to do FindControl() recursively over ucMyControl.Controls collection. Check this article for the algorithm: http://stevesmithblog.com/blog/recursive-findcontrol/

Answer (score 0):

Are you allowed to modify the user control at all? The best solution is definitely to expose either a public property or method on the user control, and then have the checkbox click event on the page communicate with the user control through the custom property or method.

FindControl may work, however you are breaking the concept of encapsulation if the page knows the ID of the button that is within the user control and shouldn't do this IMHO...